# Count number of similar values in CSV column

Tags: php, csv

I have several .csv files that I am trying to loop through and read the values of a specific column as well as count how often each value appears. For example, the third column in one of the files, we'll call it `$col[2]`, looks like this:

```
HEADER
foo
bar
bar
bar
foo
```

I can count the number of times both `foo` and `bar` appear in the file using this code:

```
$file = ('Path/To/Random/File.txt');

$fh = fopen($file, 'rb');

$tag = array();
while($col = fgetcsv($fh)) {
    $tag[$col[2]]++;
}

print_r($tag);

Result:

5
```

But, this code returns the count for all of the values in `col[2]` . How can I specify that I want the number of `foo` and `bar` values, only split into which count belongs to which value? For example, the result would look something like this:

```
echo $foo_count;
echo $bar_count;

Result:

2
3
```

Comment: `print_r($tag)` does not print the value you tell us. It should print the counts for each column value, because `$tag` is an array (i.e. `foo` and `bar`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do:

```
$file = ('Path/To/Random/File.txt');

$fh = fopen($file, 'rb');

$tag = array();
while($col = fgetcsv($fh)) {

if (isset($tag[$col[2]])) {
   $tag[$col[2]]++;
}
else {
   $tag[$col[2]] = 1;
}
```

be sure `$col[2]` actually contains the value you want to measure/iterate

once that you should have an array like, use `print_r` to check

```
'foo' => 2,
'bar' => 3
```